# Blank video for ESPN in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

When trying to watch ESPN Play in Chrome (Win 10) I don't get even the player... just blank.

I disable "Asking before using flash" but it didn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Just need to add the domain in the whitelist and it will load perfectly.